# HQL - Delete with JOIN error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql, sql-delete

Im trying to execute an HQL delete with join.. After soon searching I found that I need to create a query just like suggested HERE:

http://dasunhegoda.com/1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-table_name-for-update-in-from-clause/104/

This is my query:

```
    dao.executeByHql(
        "DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult e WHERE e.id IN "
        + "( SELECT id FROM "
            + "( SELECT x FROM FinalGradeResult x " 
            + "where x.student.id = :studentId "
            + " AND x.classDiscipline IN " + 
                + "(SELECT cd from ClassDiscipline cd " 
                + " where cd.clazz.id = :clazzId ) ) as X )",
    new HqlParameter("studentId", student.getId()), 
    new HqlParameter("clazzId", from.getId()));
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token:( near line 1, column 94 [DELETE FROM xxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.FinalGradeResult e WHERE e.id IN ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT x FROM xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.FinalGradeResult x where x.student.id = :studentId AND x.classDiscipline IN (SELECT cd from xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.entity.ClassDiscipline cd where cd.clazz.id = :clazzId ) ) as X )]
```

The error points out that the second ( is wrong, the one right after "SELECT id FROM"

**EDIT** I ve tried like this and same error occours:

```
    dao.executeByHql(
        "DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult e WHERE e.id IN "
        + "( SELECT id FROM "
        + "( SELECT x FROM FinalGradeResult x "
            + " where x.student.id = :studentId "
            + " AND x.classDiscipline.clazz.id = :clazzId )"
        + " as X )",
```

**EDIT 2** : The query like this doesnt work because of the problem described on the link I've posted in this question:

```
dao.executeByHql(
        "DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult  e WHERE e.id IN " + "( SELECT x.id FROM FinalGradeResult as x "
                + " where x.student.id = :studentId " + " AND x.classDiscipline.clazz.id = :clazzId )",
        new HqlParameter("studentId", student.getId()), new HqlParameter("clazzId", from.getId()));
```

The error is:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't specify target table 'tb_final_grade_result' for update in FROM clause
```

## SOLUTION

After trying everything out here's our conclusion:

- We cant have only one query directly because we cant have joins on DELETE.
- We cant have only 2 queries (one subquery) because we have a MYSQL BUG (described on the link provided)
- We cant have 3 queries (2 subqueries) because we cant have a subquery in the FROM clause. That's why our second query doesn´t work `(select * from (select ...))` is invalid.

So I decided to use NativeSQL to solve the problem:

```
dao.executeBySQL(
        "   delete from tb_final_grade_result where id in "
                + " (select * from ( select finalgrade1_.id from tb_final_grade_result finalgrade1_ cross join tb_class_discipline classdisci2_ "
                + " where finalgrade1_.id_class_discipline=classdisci2_.id and finalgrade1_.id_student= :studentId and classdisci2_.id_class= :clazzId ) as tmp )",
        new HqlParameter("studentId", student.getId()), new HqlParameter("clazzId", from.getId()));
```

Special thanks to @scaisEdge

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Thank ou StrawBerry. I cant create a sqlfiddle because HQL is givin syntax error and is not even generating the SQL :(

Comment: I don't understand that comment.

Comment: Hibernate cant execute the HQL because of an "unexpected token" on the HQL query. But I think the query looks fine. @scaisEdge and Consider Me are trying to help me fix it. But I'm still having the same problem

Comment: @MarcoNoronha Could you please post your solution as your own answer and accept it? That would make voting more easier!

Comment: Sure :) I'll do that;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

After trying everything out here's our conclusion:

- We cant have only one query directly because we cant have joins on DELETE.
- We cant have only 2 queries (one subquery) because we have a MYSQL BUG (described on the link provided)
- We cant have 3 queries (2 subqueries) because we cant have a subquery in the FROM clause. That's why our second query doesn´t work (select * from (select ...)) is invalid.

So I decided to use NativeSQL to solve the problem:

```
dao.executeBySQL(
        "   delete from tb_final_grade_result where id in "
                + " (select * from ( select finalgrade1_.id from tb_final_grade_result finalgrade1_ cross join tb_class_discipline classdisci2_ "
                + " where finalgrade1_.id_class_discipline=classdisci2_.id and finalgrade1_.id_student= :studentId and classdisci2_.id_class= :clazzId ) as tmp )",
        new HqlParameter("studentId", student.getId()), new HqlParameter("clazzId", from.getId()));
```

Answer (score 6):

Why do you need to use `in (select` on the same table that you are deleting from? Can't you just put the condition in the where clause?

```
DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult  e WHERE e.student.id = :studentId " + " AND e.classDiscipline.clazz.id = :clazzId )",
    new HqlParameter("studentId", student.getId()), new HqlParameter("clazzId", from.getId()));
```

Also, I'm not sure what you are referring to with the parameter `classDiscipline.clazz.id`? Is `classDiscipline` some other entity with a field named `clazz` that is yet another entity? That's what the query seems to be saying.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't do it directly like that because we cant have joins on a delete operaation. And we cant have only one subquery because mysql has a bug as explained on the question

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your original query is that you are not allowed you have inner selects anywhere but in select and where clauses. Because HQL operates in terms of entities and not tables or columns, selecting from subsets of tables doesn't make sense. See [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries.):

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses.

We had a similar issue in our project and I struggled for awhile to find a single query solution, but I'm afraid with MySQL it isn't possible due to HQL's language design.

The best I came up with was to first fetch the ids as a list, and then pass that list as a list parameter to your update. For you it might be something like:

```
Query idQuery = createQuery("select id from FinalGradeResult gr where gr.student.id = :studentId AND gr.classDiscipline IN (SELECT cd from ClassDiscipline cd where cd.clazz.id = :clazzId"));
//add parameters
List<Number> ids = query.list();
Query entityQuery = createQuery("delete from FinalGradeResult where id in (:ids)");
entityQuery.setParameterList("ids", ids);

query.executeUpdate()
```

Comment: I guess this would work also. But I already solved it by dropping down to native SQL.

Answer (score 1):

could be the position of as X is wrong

and you are repeting x instead of column name ( set `***column_name***` with the proper column name)

```
"DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult e WHERE e.id IN "
 + "( SELECT id  FROM 
    ( SELECT ***column_name ***  FROM FinalGradeResult x where x.student.id = :studentId AND x.classDiscipline IN 
    (SELECT cd from ClassDiscipline cd where cd.clazz.id = :clazzId ) as X)  )",
```

If the sibquery don't work in hibernate then try with a simple query with join

```
  DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult e 
  WHERE e.id in ( 
     SELECT  id FROM FinalGradeResult x 
     JOIN ClassDiscipline cd ON ( cd.cd.clazz.id = :clazzId  
                  and  x.classDiscipline = cd.ClassDiscipline )
     WHERE  x.student.id = :studentId);
```

Comment: Thank you scaisEdge . The column name is the "id".  I think I didnt understand your suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry the suggestion was in wromg position  ... i think is the select x from x the problem ... try chane  ***column_name***  with a valid column name (or *)   .  ... i have correct the answer ..

Comment: I still keep getting  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 102 [DELETE FROM FinalGradeResult e WHERE e.id IN ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT x.id FROM FinalGradeResult x where x.student.id = :studentId AND x.classDiscipline.clazz.id  = :clazzId ) as X )]

Comment: Also scaisEdge, if I use "*" the error changes and accuses the * to be the unexpected token.

Comment: I have suggested you that (select x from x ... could be the error) .. what do you mean for the first x that i have marked as ***column_name*** .. try explain your goal for this part of the query.

Comment: I can't seem to get HQL to run those two subqueries. Could you get Hibernate to execute a similar delete? With two sub-queries?

Comment: I suggest you firts of try to execute the query only .. without delete ... when the query work correct then add the delete ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108194/discussion-between-marco-noronha-and-scaisedge).